# Tutorials about start a private substrate network, Where the suri come from?

Tags: substrate

The [tutorials about start a private substrate network](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/private-network/).
It says:

> This example uses the secret seed generated from the key subcommand
> into the keystore. In this tutorial, the secret seed generated was
> 0x563d22ef5f00e589e07445a3ad88bb92efaa897d7f73a4543d9ac87476434e65, so
> the --suri command-line option specifies that string to insert the key
> into the keystore:

My wondering is where the `suri` come from? the article doesn't demo very clearly.

I log what I did:

```
$ ./target/release/node-template key generate --scheme Sr25519 --password-interactive
Key password: 123456
Secret phrase `raw glory squeeze allow demand erase ensure car hair dry tobacco mule` is account:
  Secret seed:       0xa80c9a2c2c96ac61a548a358c81aa07a519af00e7b3fc25f06761e2a5af42044         # use the string as next step's input, import to node01
  Public key (hex):  0x780a4cd1e018e5433c061da3c28ad1ff33a59da6cd8b750a5a37f3e7fb69fc62
  Public key (SS58): 5En6fQsu3ju9zo2PvwptfnZZWrrWWs9zsBt1WuF9U8TGNWFj
  Account ID:        0x780a4cd1e018e5433c061da3c28ad1ff33a59da6cd8b750a5a37f3e7fb69fc62
  SS58 Address:      5En6fQsu3ju9zo2PvwptfnZZWrrWWs9zsBt1WuF9U8TGNWFj                           #put this in the chain-spec file, aura.authorities
$ ./target/release/node-template key inspect --password-interactive --scheme Ed25519 0xa80c9a2c2c96ac61a548a358c81aa07a519af00e7b3fc25f06761e2a5af42044
Key password: 123456
Secret Key URI `0xa80c9a2c2c96ac61a548a358c81aa07a519af00e7b3fc25f06761e2a5af42044` is account:
  Secret seed:       0xa80c9a2c2c96ac61a548a358c81aa07a519af00e7b3fc25f06761e2a5af42044
  Public key (hex):  0x9c1726a7a0cca51dc506a06789b0781260e999ccafd687799c275a52916b1b01
  Public key (SS58): 5FbNCp3ZHWzFGQkS1PRt9SPUs16zAHk1WhC2CWTQ97nsE2yk
  Account ID:        0x9c1726a7a0cca51dc506a06789b0781260e999ccafd687799c275a52916b1b01
  SS58 Address:      5FbNCp3ZHWzFGQkS1PRt9SPUs16zAHk1WhC2CWTQ97nsE2yk                           #put this in the chain-spec file, grandpa.authorities 

$ ./target/release/node-template key generate --scheme Sr25519 --password-interactive
Key password: 123456
Secret phrase `caution evil word live concert suit cousin crisp tobacco lizard wheat banner` is account:
  Secret seed:       0x52e547fc68fed1d7e97be6232434ccc51d9cfe1cc237820d9cf3a559dd2be6e8         # use the string as next step's input, import to node02
  Public key (hex):  0xced1d44c697e75fd3c51096e869d204f9aec8620ab3422d3e81ec6870fe81c41
  Public key (SS58): 5Gjt44znWzR8eu7fDH7cRey8KavbHQuoraD1a3ttYPsVpn75
  Account ID:        0xced1d44c697e75fd3c51096e869d204f9aec8620ab3422d3e81ec6870fe81c41
  SS58 Address:      5Gjt44znWzR8eu7fDH7cRey8KavbHQuoraD1a3ttYPsVpn75                           #put this in the chain-spec file, aura.authorities

$ ./target/release/node-template key inspect --password-interactive --scheme Ed25519 0x52e547fc68fed1d7e97be6232434ccc51d9cfe1cc237820d9cf3a559dd2be6e8
Key password: 123456
Secret Key URI `0x52e547fc68fed1d7e97be6232434ccc51d9cfe1cc237820d9cf3a559dd2be6e8` is account:
  Secret seed:       0x52e547fc68fed1d7e97be6232434ccc51d9cfe1cc237820d9cf3a559dd2be6e8
  Public key (hex):  0x1d2259132f8ad2d6cb92ce397c97dfe86226708130c94ca3fa10651276de514f
  Public key (SS58): 5CiuT1fKfVZGeok2T68g4zx1RCMCmZbHD7zFUrguLeiuCZ1g
  Account ID:        0x1d2259132f8ad2d6cb92ce397c97dfe86226708130c94ca3fa10651276de514f
  SS58 Address:      5CiuT1fKfVZGeok2T68g4zx1RCMCmZbHD7zFUrguLeiuCZ1g                           #put this in the chain-spec file, grandpa.authorities 






./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node01 \
--chain customSpecRaw.json \
--suri 0xa80c9a2c2c96ac61a548a358c81aa07a519af00e7b3fc25f06761e2a5af42044 \                     # Secret seed
--password-interactive \
--key-type aura

./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node01 \
--chain customSpecRaw.json \
--suri 0xa80c9a2c2c96ac61a548a358c81aa07a519af00e7b3fc25f06761e2a5af42044 \
--password-interactive \
--key-type gran


./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node02 \
--chain customSpecRaw.json \
--suri 0x52e547fc68fed1d7e97be6232434ccc51d9cfe1cc237820d9cf3a559dd2be6e8 \
--password-interactive \
--key-type aura


./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node02 \
--chain customSpecRaw.json \
--suri 0x52e547fc68fed1d7e97be6232434ccc51d9cfe1cc237820d9cf3a559dd2be6e8 \
--password-interactive \
--key-type gran
```

After import key to keystore

```
$ ls /tmp/node01/chains/local_testnet/keystore
61757261780a4cd1e018e5433c061da3c28ad1ff33a59da6cd8b750a5a37f3e7fb69fc62        6772616e780a4cd1e018e5433c061da3c28ad1ff33a59da6cd8b750a5a37f3e7fb69fc62
$ ls /tmp/node02/chains/local_testnet/keystore
61757261ced1d44c697e75fd3c51096e869d204f9aec8620ab3422d3e81ec6870fe81c41        6772616eced1d44c697e75fd3c51096e869d204f9aec8620ab3422d3e81ec6870fe81c41
```

I restart node1,node2, but The result is :

```
Idle (1 peers), best: #94 (0x8634…b5c9), finalized #0 (0x4f9a…68f0), ⬇ 40 B/s ⬆ 0.1kiB/s
```

finalized block number is always `0`

I tried the old version of the topic `start a private network`, it use the `subkey` to generate the keys. It worked. but I failed when reference the new tutorial.

Where am I wrong？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me to post a correct answer:

```
$./target/release/node-template key insert --base-path /tmp/node01 \
--chain customSpecRaw.json \
--scheme ed25519 \
--suri 0xa80c9a2c2c96ac61a548a358c81aa07a519af00e7b3fc25f06761e2a5af42044 \
--password-interactive \
--key-type gran
```

when import grandpa key, add this: `--scheme ed25519` .

after do this, It works.

```
Idle (1 peers), best: #95 (0xf51f…65a8), finalized #93 (0x072b…192a), ⬇ 0.5kiB/s ⬆ 0.6kiB/s
```

please reference: https://core.tetcoin.org/docs/en/knowledgebase/integrate/subkey#inserting-keys-to-a-nodes-keystore

Answer (score 1):

There are a section called **Generate your own keys**.

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/private-network/#generate-your-own-keys

The `Secret Seed` is your `suri`

And here some nice script to insert the keys easily

https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/tutorials/solutions/private-chain-v3/key-insert/insert-keys.sh

Comment: Hi Phillip, I update the question. I add more detail What I did. Could you please help to identify the wher I am wrong?